# Can I install git on a Chromebook without an alternate OS

Tags: git, google-chrome, installation, chromebook

Is it possible to install `git` on a Chrome OS? I'm working on a Chromebook and I do not want to install another OS.
From the command line, `Chronos@localhost` does not accept the `apt` command.
Do I need a different package manager?

Comment: After some research, I found a fix, so for anyone else who would like version control on a chromebook without resorting to a dual operating system, see Michal Siwek's open source project Chromebrew. It is a package manager to install git on a chromebook. You can read about it and download it at https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew

Answer (score 1):

To use version control on a chromebook without resorting to a dual operating system, see Michal Siwek's open source project Chromebrew.
It is a package manager to install `git` on a chromebook. You can read about it and download it at https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew.